# Interference between onErrorResume() and thenReturn()

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I cannot understand how [`Flux.onErrorContinue()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#onErrorContinue-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) works. Based on [Does Reactor onErrorContinue operator let the original sequence continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69510106/2886891) I created a similar example to understand it better, but I am lost.

Especially weird is the interference between [`onErrorContinue()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#onErrorContinue-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) and [`thenReturn()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#thenReturn-V-).

I have the following code:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

class OnErrorContinueTest {
    @Test
    void testOnErrorContinue() {
        Flux.range(1, 3)
                .doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("Main-1: " + n))
                .flatMap(this::processElement)
                .doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("Main-2: " + n)) // Why does onErrorContinue recovers that line, if it is after?
                .onErrorContinue((ex, o) -> System.err.println("    Error processing " + o + " - " + ex.getMessage()))
                .doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("Main-3: " + n))
                .subscribe();
    }

    @Test
    void testOnErrorResume() {
        Flux.range(1, 3)
                .doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("Main-1: " + n))
                .flatMap(n -> this.processElement(n)
                        .doOnError(ex -> System.err.println("    Error processing " + n + " - " + ex.getMessage()))
                        .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty()))
                .doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("Main-2: " + n))
                .subscribe();
    }

    Mono<Integer> processElement(Integer i) {
        return Mono.just(i)
                .doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("    Process-1: " + n))
                .doOnNext(n -> {
                    if (n == 2) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Forcing exception for " + n);
                    }
                })
                .doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("    Process-2: " + n))
                .thenReturn(i) // Why does onErrorContinue recovers everything after that line?
                .doOnNext(n -> System.out.println("    Process-3: " + n))
                ;
    }
}
```

`testOnErrorResume()` produces exactly what I would expect:

```
Main-1: 1
    Process-1: 1
    Process-2: 1
    Process-3: 1
Main-2: 1
Main-1: 2
    Process-1: 2
    Error while processing 2 - Forcing exception for 2
Main-1: 3
    Process-1: 3
    Process-2: 3
    Process-3: 3
Main-2: 3
```

However, `testOnErrorContinue()` produces:

```
Main-1: 1
    Process-1: 1
    Process-2: 1
    Process-3: 1
Main-2: 1
Main-3: 1
Main-1: 2
    Process-1: 2
    Error while processing 2 - Forcing exception for 2
    Process-3: 2     -- UNEXPECTED - WHY IS THIS PRINTED?
Main-2: 2            -- UNEXPECTED - WHY IS THIS PRINTED?
Main-3: 2
Main-1: 3
    Process-1: 3
    Process-2: 3
    Process-3: 3
Main-2: 3
Main-3: 3
```

My doubts:

1. Why does `onErrorContinue()` recover inside the `processElement()` method? It seems like `thenReturn()` has something to do with it, but cannot understand how, because the [`thenReturn()`s documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#thenReturn-V-) states

   > On an error in the original `Mono`, the error signal is propagated instead.
2. Why does `onErrorContinue()` recover before it is called? Why is the code `System.out.println("Main-2: " + n)` executed?

Comment: https://devdojo.com/ketonemaniac/reactor-onerrorcontinue-vs-onerrorresume